# NSwag - provide additional information for the expected data in a controller action

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, nswag

I have a controller action that accepts data in the form of an array of objects (Complex object called `ControlLinePointDto`). For reasons described in my question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50852571/net-core-controller-to-update-array-but-only-with-included-properties), I read this into a `JArray` rather than a `ControlLinePointDto[]`. I do this in multiple places with different objects.

How can I change the documentation (`NSwag`) so that it is documented (including example) as a `ControlLinePointDto[]`, rather than `[]`?

```
[HttpPost("AddPoints")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(List<ControlLinePointDto>), 200)]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddPoints(int ControlLineId, [FromBody] JArray pointSetJson){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the docs type this way:

```
[JsonSchemaType(typeof(MyDto[]), FromBody] JArray array
```

https://github.com/RSuter/NJsonSchema/blob/master/src/NJsonSchema/Annotations/JsonSchemaTypeAttribute.cs#L19